# Dynamic discontinuous excel ranges in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How can I dynamically extend the number of rows in two columns that I need to copy to another sheet?

First, I identify the number of rows I need to include and store in `totrows`:

```
Dim totrows As Integer
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    totrows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Next, I am trying to extend the two columns of interest ("B" and "G") so that the range includes that `totrows` rows. For a static example, if `totrows`=100 then I would have:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B2:B102,G2:G102").copy
End With
```

I then paste them into my second sheet with:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Paste
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been trying the `&` without luck - I had been putting the comma outside of the quotes(!)

Answer (score 3):

```
.Range("B2:B102,G2:G102").copy
```

can be written as

```
.Range("B2:B" & totrows & ",G2:G" & totrows).Copy
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way without using `.Copy` or `.Paste` would be this:

```
Sub Copy()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
    Dim totrows As Integer

    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
    Set wsCopy = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsPaste = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    totrows = wsCopy.Range("A" & wsCopy.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    wsPaste.Range("A1:B" & totrows) = wsCopy.Range("A2:A" & totrows, "G2:G" & totrows).Value


End Sub
```

This way your directly putting the Values into the `Range` you want.